# GoQt fatal error: QAbstractAnimation :no such file or directory

Tags: qt, go

I tried to compile GoQt for developing desctop applications. I followed the instruction from the official wiki guide on the Qt website. When I tried to `go run` an example from the examples folder, I got an error:

> go run '/home/pinkya_rabbit/workspace/go1programs/src/qt/qt/internal/examples/uitools/calculator/calculator.go'
>   workspace/go1programs/src/github.com/therecipe/qt/core/core.cpp:9:30: fatal error: QAbstractAnimation: no such file or directory
>   compilation terminated.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Are you using `dep` or using vendoring?

Comment: When I asked this question (a year ago) I followed from Qt website to guide. Don't remember where.

Comment: For those using vendors and experiencing this problem take a look at the following issue on [github.com/therecipe/qt](https://github.com/therecipe/qt/issues/615).