# Go-QT Binding: QAbstractAnimation No such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt, go, raspberry-pi

I am using go-QT binding(https://github.com/therecipe/qt). My code is compiling & working good for amd64 but when I try to cross compile it for arm devices (Raspberrypi), it gives below error. Please advise how to solve this issue

```
**src/github.com/therecipe/qt/core/core.cpp:9:30: fatal error: 
QAbstractAnimation: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.**

Environment Variables

GOARCH="arm"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/minhaj/GoLang"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
GOARM=""
CC="arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -marm -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-
map=/tmp/go-build728594690=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
CXX="arm-linux-gnueabi-g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"

Compilation Result
go build -v IndoorMass/
crypto
encoding
encoding/base64
crypto/sha256
unicode/utf16
flag
encoding/json
golang.org/x/image/math/fixed
github.com/golang/freetype/raster
golang.org/x/image/font
github.com/icza/mjpeg
github.com/golang/freetype/truetype
github.com/skip2/go-qrcode/bitset
github.com/skip2/go-qrcode/reedsolomon
path/filepath
io/ioutil
github.com/skip2/go-qrcode
container/list
golang.org/x/net/context
github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3
IndoorMass/General
github.com/tidwall/match
github.com/tidwall/gjson
compress/gzip
crypto/subtle
crypto/cipher
crypto/aes
internal/syscall/unix
math/rand
math/big
crypto/rand
crypto/des
crypto/elliptic
crypto/sha512
encoding/asn1
crypto/ecdsa
crypto/hmac
crypto/internal/cipherhw
crypto/md5
crypto/rc4
crypto/rsa
crypto/sha1
crypto/dsa
crypto/x509/pkix
encoding/hex
encoding/pem
internal/nettrace
internal/singleflight
net
crypto/x509
vendor/golang_org/x/crypto/chacha20poly1305/internal/chacha20
vendor/golang_org/x/crypto/poly1305
vendor/golang_org/x/crypto/chacha20poly1305
vendor/golang_org/x/crypto/curve25519
crypto/tls
vendor/golang_org/x/net/http2/hpack
vendor/golang_org/x/net/idna
vendor/golang_org/x/net/lex/httplex
vendor/golang_org/x/text/transform
vendor/golang_org/x/text/unicode/norm
vendor/golang_org/x/text/width
mime
mime/quotedprintable
net/textproto
mime/multipart
net/http/httptrace
net/http/internal
path
net/http
IndoorMass/Server
github.com/kaey/framebuffer
os/exec
github.com/mrmorphic/hwio
github.com/DexterInd/GrovePi/Software/Go/grovepi
IndoorMass/Sensor
github.com/therecipe/qt
github.com/therecipe/qt/core
# github.com/therecipe/qt/core
src/github.com/therecipe/qt/core/core.cpp:9:30: fatal error: 
QAbstractAnimation: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
IndoorMass/DB
IndoorMass/Manager
```

Comment: The error is the same as https://stackoverflow.com/q/42433946 But it has no answer now..

Comment: May be no one knows the answer :)

Comment: I installed the QT package without Android support and when i run go main i get the same error. OP, did you solve the problem ?

Comment: @SuburbanFilth, I moved to Go-GTK and built my application on that...